# ways to Java for Loops

Tags: java

Hi I am just really confused on how to ask the user for a starting number and an ending number.

Use the for loop to iterate through the range of integers.

Display:

list of even numbers in that range
the number of even numbers displayed

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Assignment8 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    int count;
    int end;
    int start;

    System.out.println("Enter the starting number");
    start = keyboard.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter the ending number");
    end = keyboard.nextInt();

    for(int count=start; count <= end; count++){

        if( count % 2 == 0){
            System.out.print(i + " ");
            System.out.println("Enter the next number");
           i = keyboard.nextInt();

        }
    }  
    }
}
```

This is what i got so far but I don't know how to start a list, and to count them.

I just don't understand how it is done it is not a certain amount the user can do as many numbers as they want or any number.

Comment: I don't get what you want to do in the `for`-loop. If you wish to output `i`, you'll do something like this: `System.out.println(i);` instead of `i = keyboard.nextInt();`

Comment: I ment to put count for i sorry i am trying to get a loop to go through and ask for a number if it is even it would go into a list. at the end it would show all the even numbers entered and how many were entered

Comment: That's not what you asked... "Hi i am just really confused on how to ask the user for a starting number and an ending number. Use the for loop to iterate through the range of integers"

Comment: The question is not clear enough. What I'm thinking you are asking is how to ask the user for a range of integers and then print to the screen all of the even numbers in that range and then, print the number of even numbers. Is that correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to make your code as follows:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MainApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        int end;
        int start;
        List<Integer> evenNumbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        System.out.println("Enter the starting number");
        start = keyboard.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter the ending number");
        end = keyboard.nextInt();

        for (int i = start; i <= end; i++) {

            if (i % 2 == 0) {
                evenNumbers.add(i);
            }
        }

        System.out.println("There are " + evenNumbers.size() + " even numbers between [" +start +"," + end + "]");
        System.out.println("The numbers are: " + evenNumbers.toString());

    }
}
```

If you need the numbers between the **start** and the **end** change the for loop as follows:

```
i++
for (int i = start; i < end; i++)
```

Comment: Why are you reassigning `i` inside the loop?

Comment: please be more accurate so I can see the problem? There is no double reassinging. I think that you are missing something while voting down my answer.

Comment: Sorry this is still no clear related to the code above, I have made it as clean and clear as I could. Please refresh the page.

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class EvenNumber {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        int end;
        int start;
        List<Integer> evenNumbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        System.out.println("Enter the starting number");
        start = keyboard.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter the ending number");
        end = keyboard.nextInt();
        keyboard.close();
        for (int i = start; i <= end; i++) {
            if (i % 2 == 0) {
                evenNumbers.add(i);
            }
        }
        if (!evenNumbers.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println("Even Numbers between " + start + " and " + end);
            System.out.println(evenNumbers);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, if you want to optimize the performance a little, you only really need to check if the start number is odd. If it is, just add 1 to it. Then you can just use `i += 2` instead of `i++` after each loop iteration and don't need to check whether the number is even in the loop because it always is.

About your actual problem: just remove the last two lines inside your loop. You don't want the user to input some number every time the loop prints a number, right?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you have declared a count variable and asking to enter another number in the if block but i have modified your for loop and it prints all even numbers in the range between the start and end

```
for (int i =start; i<=end, i++){
if(i % 2 = 0){
System.out.print(i + " ");
   }
}
```